# CSS - Swap Columns

Tags: css, wordpress

I have two columns on my page:

```
Left-Column    Right-Column
```

On mobile and tablet devices, I want the Right-Column to display before the left one. For e.g.:

```
<p>Right-Column</p>
<p>Left-Column</p>
```

Anyone how to do this using CSS? I know I can do it using Bootstrap but the wordpress template is not designed using Bootstrap.

Thanks

Comment: How are we supposed to supply a working answer for you without seeing the relevant code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about browser support you can use `flexbox` for this.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.container > div {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
    .left-col {
        order: 2;
    }

    .right-col {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scdvL0Ly/

This should work in all major browsers and in IE10 and up. See [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Some Browsers still require prefixes for this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I would use flex-box and a media query:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap
}
#parent > div {
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
  #parent > div {
      flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
  #left {
    order: 2;
  }
  #right {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">
    <span>Left</span>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <span>Right</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very difficult, just play with the positioning in media queries opposite to the width of the other element:

```
.left {
    width: 75%;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    width: 25%;
    background: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .left {
        left: 25%;
    }

    .right {
        right: 75%;
    }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8L26fgth/)

Comment: this code doesn't work as expected. On smaller viewports the red block should be placed above the blue block.

Comment: Really? "On mobile and tablet devices, I want the Right-Column to display before the left one"

Comment: the columns have to be swapped but also stacked as requested by OP

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan possibly yours would be a correct answer if OP would comment on anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You question is not so clear.

But in the light of the present knowledge , keep `float:right` for Left-Column and 
`float:left`   for Right-Column .

See the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/srmpx6Lp/2/

If you give your code , i can better understand the need

Comment: This does reverse the order. But the OP would also like them stacked on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `<table>` you can also use `direction: rtl` for parent and `direction: ltr` to child elements.